# How to sum the Doubles in Map<Integer, Double> of object in a list after using Java Stream grouping by

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've got the following class:

```
public class Response {
     private final Map<Integer, Double> totalListPerKey;
     private final String key;
}
```

And I've got a `Collection<Response> responses` that would need to group by key and sum up the Double value in map totalListPerKey for all the items in the collection based off of the matching key (Integer) in totalListPerKey.

i.e.

```
Response A = new Response(new HashMap[(1234,325.3),(2345,123.5)],test)
Response B = new Response(new HashMap[(1234,454.3),(2345,50)],test)
```

Expected Result:

```
Object(test,new HashMap[(1234,779.6),(2345,173.5)])
```

Answer (score 0):

After your explanation

```
Map<Integer, Set<Double>> collectSetOfDoublesByIntKey = objsWithIntAndDouble.stream().collect( Collectors.groupingBy(Obj::getInt, Collectors.mapping(Obj::getDouble, Collectors.toSet()) ) );
Map<Integer, Double> collectSumOfDoublesByIntKey = objsWithIntAndDouble.stream().collect( Collectors.groupingBy(Obj::getInt, Collectors.summingDouble(Obj::getDouble) ) );
```

Comment: The issue that I'm trying to solve is I have a list of objects with a string of key and Map<Int, Double> inside that object.  That's more complicated as I need to group the list of objects with matching key then sum up the Double in the Map<Int,Double> list per item.  So your answer didn't really help.

Comment: You have to group the list by key and then sum them up on every single object and keep them separated, or put them altogether from the list?

Comment: keep them separated

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the keys of a response, say Response B, check if it is present in Response A, if present assign the sum to the value of that key in Response A(or some other but final).

Edit: if the key is not present just copy the entry to the final Response for future groupings.

If you want to keep the values seperately, then you should keep a map like

`private final Map<Integer, List<Double>> totalListPerKey;`  a list of doubles instead of just one double value.